# Cannot read properties of null (reading "width") in Three.js React component

Tags: reactjs, three.js, 3d

I have a Three.js app and I have a problem. I have a few files: 
main.js: 
it looks exactly like the code from [this](https://youtube.com/watch?v=1TeMXIWRrqE&si=EnSIkaIECMiOmarE) video. All I did was to wrap everything into a function so I could load 5 3D models dinamically, and not create 5 js files that do the same.

And the React component:

```
import { displayObject } from "../main"

export default function Atraction() {
  setTimeout(() => { displayObject(myArgs) }, 3000)
  return (
    <canvas className="webgl-1"></canvas>
  )
}
```

I get the error:

> Cannot read proprety of null(reading "width")

It refers to the `canvas` element that I am trying to access. What should I do?

Comment: I haven't watched the video you linked, but I did look at the source code and it looks different enough from what I would expect you to have that I think you need to provide your displayObject function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, it is hard to figure out exactly how your code looks from the small fragment. But, what you have provided can probably be improved. What happens if the page takes longer to load than 3 seconds (slow internet for example)? setTimeout will break because the html hasn't been rendered yet. Also, do you really want people to have to wait 3 seconds for the objects to load if their computer loads it in 500ms?

useEffect runs as soon as the DOM has rendered or whenever it reloads. It is safe to say we only want to establish the scene once, so we can use a guard at the start of a useEffect hook to make sure it only ever runs once (when the component first renders).

Additionally, with react functional components, we can use useRef to get a hook into the DOM. While technically we could use the id of the component to render our ThreeJS code, using a useRef() hook tells every programmer that we are going to be editing the DOM later -- it communicates intention which is helpful to other programmers to read.

```
let rendered = false;

export function Component() {
  const ref = useRef() // this allows us to refer to the dom element once it has been created

  // useeffect happens as soon as Component() has rendered to html
  useEffect(() => {
    if (rendered) { // this makes sure the scene isn't created more than once even if Component() changes/re-renders
      return;
    }
    rendered = true;

    const scene = new THREE.Scene();
    const renderer = new THREE.Renderer(... etc.);

    // ... setup scene/camera/renderer ect.

    // best to separate loading/adding-to-scene out of one function to avoid brittle code
    const car = loadObject('etc/car.gltf');
    scene.add(car)
    const house = loadObject('etc/house.gltf');
    scene.add(house)

    // since the useEffect only runs once dom has rendered, ref will now refer to the dom 
    ref.current.appendChild(renderer.domElement)

  });

  return <div ref={ref} ></div>
}

function loadObject(objectLocation) {
  
   // load object at objectLocation

   return loadedObject
  
}
```

Additionally, if my memory serves me correctly,

```
    ref.current.appendChild(renderer.domElement)
```

creates a new canvas component itself and puts it inside the target component. Therefore, the root component (as I have shown) is probably best to simply to be a `<div />`. (citation needed)

Since I haven't seen the rest of your code: if this doesn't help you, please post more code and I will update my answer to better aid you.